# SaltStack to trigger webservices

Tags: web-services, salt-stack

I'm currently trying SaltStack that seems to have some cool features. But I miss a module from Ansible :

In SaltStack what is the equivalent of the Ansible's module "uri" ?

Example in Ansible :

```
- name: using webservices
  uri:
    url: http://.../v1/method
    method: PUT
    body: {{ lookup('template', 'job.j2') }}
    body_format: json
    status_code: 201,409
    HEADER_Content-Type: "application/json"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [http.query](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.http.html#salt.states.http.query) module.

For example:

```
http://example.com/restapi:
  http.query:
    - match: 'SUCCESS'
    - data_render: True
    - header_file: /tmp/headers.txt
    - header_render: True
    - cookies: True
    - persist_session: True
```